# How can I uninstall Lock Screen Widget from my Nexus One?

Tags: nexus-one, uninstallation, device-administrator

I am trying to Lock Screen Widget, But I am getting the following error from 'adb logcat' as I uninstall it.

> W/PackageManager(   96): Not removing
>   package
>   com.droidmania.lockscreenwidget: has
>   active device admin

Can u please tell me how can I uninstall it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to remove the Lock Screen Widget app from `Menu -> Settings -> Location & security -> Select device administrators` screen before trying to uninstall it.